# VBA Word: Create a caption label and replace an existing label with the new one

Tags: vba, ms-word, caption

Good morning.

I have plenty experiencie with VBA in Excel but never used it in Word.
This is my problem:

I need to replace all the caption labels called "Figura" with "Figure".

I have no idea how to do it and the macros I've found dont seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Checked for macros here in Stack Overflow but none seemed to work.

Comment: You can record a macro in MS Word, same as Excel. Then check what it did, and see how the objects and methods can be used to automate the task

Comment: The biggest difference between Excel and Word is that a [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range) now refers to a length of text instead of a collection of worksheet cells. And that the top-level object you're working with is a [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document) instead of a `Workbook`.

Comment: The formal Caption label is a registry entry on the user's computer, although the label found in the Caption is text. When I say "formal Caption lable" I mean the ones listed when using the insert Caption dialog. This may also have an effect on the Table of Figures.

Comment: You don't even need a macro for this - a simple Find/Replace will do...